# Simple Spring-Maven HelloWorld -> appContext.xml not found?

Tags: spring

I am having some difficulties with the simplest maven-spring app. Actually, `BeanFactory` does not find the `appContext.xml` file, despite it is located in the resources dir and copied properly into the target dir. Here's my main class, the dir structure and the error:

```
// MAIN CLASS
package sas.test.spring;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        BeanFactory fact = new XmlBeanFactory((Resource) new FileInputStream("appContext.xml"));

        GreetingService gs = (GreetingService) fact.getBean("greetingService");

        gs.sayGreeting();

    }
}
```

The directory structure after `mvn compile`:

```
testspring002
|--src
|  `--main
|     |--java
|     |  `--sas
|     |     `--test
|     |        `--spring
|     |           |--App.java
|     |           |--GreetingService.java
|     |           `--GreetingServiceImpl.java
|     `--resources
|        `--appContext.xml
...
`--target
   `--classes
      |--appContext.xml
      `--sas
         `--test
            `--spring
               |--App.class
               |--GreetingService.class
               `--GreetingServiceImpl.class
```

And here is the error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/java/maven-2.2.0/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/java/maven-2.2.0 -Dfile.encoding=MacRoman -classpath /usr/share/java/maven-2.2.0/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --no-plugin-updates --strict-checksums --update-snapshots -f /Users/sas/Development/workspace_idea/testspring002/pom.xml org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:java
+ Enabling strict checksum verification on all artifact downloads.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testspring002
[INFO]    task-segment: [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:java]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[INFO] artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin: checking for updates from central
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: default-cli}]
Hello World!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

appContext.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks, that hint did it. Didn't realize that FileInputStream might be an issue. However, I use ApplicationContext now and it works:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"appContext.xml"});
```

Thanks & Cheers

Comment: ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is the right answer.  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the app context XML is in /classes, that means it's in the CLASSPATH.  I'd recommend calling getResourceAsStream() from the class loader to get the InputStream instead of FileInputStream.